# Unable to take Postgres backup using gpg key on centos

Tags: postgresql, gnupg

-bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_dump ia_test | gpg -r 6DB7B450 -e -o /tmp/backup.sql.gpg
gpg: 6DB7B450: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key

**Also run the following and looks like it shows the same gpg --list-key gpg: checking the trustdb gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model gpg: depth: 0 valid: 1 signed: 0 trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u gpg: next trustdb check due at 2019-10-10 /root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg pub 2048R/6DB7B450 2019-10-09 [expires: 2019-10-10] uid Test (Test Key)  sub 2048R/F06A02C0 2019-10-09 [expires: 2019-10-10]**

Comment: Hi, can you put this content in comments into the question by editing it, we can use comments to ask for clarification on questions or answers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with postgresql.  If you replace "pg_dump" with "echo", you would have the same issue. (or wouldn't you?)